# Configuring Org-mode to open PDFs with evince

Tags: pdf, viewers, org-mode

sorry for asking this kind of question here... but didn't know who else could help me with this.

I'm starting to use `org-mode` to export text to LaTeX.

My problem is that it opens the generated PDF with `ebook-viewer` (it is a EPUB, CHM reader) instead of using evince.

*Question*

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour and configure `evince`to be the default viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the variable `org-file-apps` so that

```
 Extension \.pdf\'
```

is followed by

```
 Command: evince %s
```

instead of `Use default`.  This will affect opening of all `pdf` files by `org-mode`.